# Положение вкладки Project в настройках по умолчанию

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains

Пользуюсь Intellij IDEA. Замечательный инструмент, полностью устраивает, но каждый раз при создании нового проекта приходится руками переносить вкладки с левой панели на правую и наоборот : [image: перемещение вкладок]

Вроде бы мелочь, но после 50-го проекта как то поднадоело.

Вопрос такой: как нибудь можно настроить положение этих вкладок по умолчанию ? в настройках просмотрел, не увидел, в инете искал, но видимо неправильно запрос формулирую.

Comment: Нет, не регулируется, но можно написать плагин. В конце концов Идея это просто Java-app.

Comment: Спасибо. Жаль конечно, ну значит напишем.